# Which is the header file that implements float4 operation in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, header

I know the make_float4 constructor is in vector_functions.h, but which is the header file that implements float4 operation in CUDA?

Thanks.

Comment: Some `float4` operators (+,-,*,+=,-=, etc.) are defined in `/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc/helper_math.h`, however that is not considered a standard CUDA header file.  It's part of the samples package.

Comment: Can someone shed some light upon why CUDA does not include these elementary operations per default?

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a standard cuda header file (i.e. one that will be found by `nvcc` automatically, such as those in `/usr/local/cuda/include`) that implements a variety of `float4` operators.

However the "helper" header file at:

```
/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc/helper_math.h
```

(example path on linux) which gets installed with the cuda samples, defines a number of arithmetic operators on `float4` quantities.

Comment: Yep. They defined some utility operations in helper_math.h, and I made use of it in my project. Thanks again.

Comment: How can we be sure that we get (for example) hardware accelerated dot products using this header file?

Comment: I want to make sure I generate the correct PTX instruction , e.g., dp4a http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#integer-arithmetic-instructions-dp4a